# Using ng-select and if else statement in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the value from a simple ng-select to the controller and then use an if statement to check if the selected value is equal to a value that I require, as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectAnswerPhaseOneQuestionOne">Select answer:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectAnswerPhaseOneQuestionOne"
    data-ng-model="questionOneAnswer" data-ng-dropdown required
    name="type">
      <option></option>
      <option value="True">True</option>
      <option value="False">False</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<button data-ng-click="submitPhaseOneAnswers()"
class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.questionOneAnswer = '';

$scope.submitPhaseOneAnswers = function () {
  var score = 0;
  if($scope.questionOneAnswer == 'True') {
    score = score + 10;
    alert('Your score is now ' + score);
  }
}
```

In simple terms, the above doesn't work and the button click simply bypasses the if statement. Finally, the above code I've outlined actually contains 4x the select groups I have in my HTML that on button press I need to evaluate if they are 'True' or 'False.

Comment: Can you look up in debugger the value of $scope.questionOneAnswer? Did you add $scope to your controller dependency?

Comment: Be great if the code would even attempt to execute, but it doesn't at all. No alert pop-up and even added a console log? Sorry, yes, I've declared $scope in my controller of course.

Comment: Is your question answered now?

Comment: Be great to hear if anyone has any suggestions for this?

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors. I provided you the working solution. Simply use it.

Comment: Hi Alexander, yes your solution does solve the problem and answers my question in principle. However, I must point out that your solution only worked when the controller declaration is explicitly declared in the HTML. Now, this poses a potential problem if I'm using multiple controllers in one document for the same content, which I've now managed to fix myself by simply changing the ng-model from 'ng-model="questionOneAnswer"' to 'ng-model="questionAnswers.questionOneAnswer"' and creating an empty scope object in the JS. Fixed the problem and I can now use multiple controllers in one HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-options`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.options = ['True', 'False'];

  $scope.submitPhaseOneAnswers = function () {
    var score = 0;
    
    if($scope.questionOneAnswer == 'True') {
      score += 10;
    }
    
    alert('Your score is now ' + score);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="form-group" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label for="selectAnswerPhaseOneQuestionOne">Select answer:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectAnswerPhaseOneQuestionOne"
    ng-model="questionOneAnswer" name="type" ng-options="option as option for option in options"></select>
    <button ng-click="submitPhaseOneAnswers()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the suggestion. Although I'm still getting the same problem. Please note that I've not put the 'ng-controller' statement in my HTML as I've been advised before that it's not needed as it gets executed anyway, or should I change this perhaps? Also, the button is outside of the form so I'm not sure if this is causing the issues as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your code step by step.

1. Check the controller name in HTML file and JS file (has same name)
2. Put console.log() in function $scope.submitPhaseOneAnswers() to check if it is running when click button.
3. If the function works well, maybe $scope.questionOneAnswer = '' causes error.

Comment: Okay, just tried your suggestion by placing it in a console log and the following came up in the console.. 'Error: too much recursion....'